# Mysql query to exclude a period of time

Tags: mysql

I want to exclude records in a table from 00:00AM to 06:00AM

This works but it's not fast enough.

```
select * from table_x where archive != 1 
and (   
   moment not like '% 00:%' 
   and moment not like '% 01:%' 
   and moment not like '% 02:%' 
   and moment not like '% 03:%' 
   and moment not like '% 04:%' 
   and moment not like '% 05:%'
);
```

The field "moment" is a datetime type.
example : "2014-01-24 01:02:03"

I want to optimze the query.

[EDIT]
It has to exclude everyday from 00:00AM to 06:00AM.

Comment: `SELECT ... WHERE moment NOT BETWEEN '2014-01-24 00:00' AND '2014-01-24 06:00'` that'll be $500

Comment: Ok I was not clear for the point that it should exclude everyday.

Comment: `WHERE TIME(moment) NOT BETWEEN '00:00' AND '06:00'` .. another $500

Comment: I'm ruined!! :-[  
Thank you. I will give it a try to see if it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an index-efficient way to do this with your current table schema. You would need to add an additional column for something like `HOUR(moment)` or just a boolean, populate it from your data, and index it appropriately.

Comment: You're actually right. A field for the hour and another for the minutes would be perfect. We already have one for the day, another for the month and finally another for the year... BUT we won't have the time to make such changes.
So I guess I will have to use the "between" condition.

Comment: You could also split the datetime column into 2: `date` and `time`